# Unable to use XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode on XML with Two Namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to parse the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<A2AAnf:MPPPPPP xsi:schemaLocation="urn:A2AAnf:xsd:$MPPPPPP.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:A2AAnf="urn:A2AAnf:xsd:$MPPPPPP">
<A2AAnf:Num>0</A2AAnf:Num>
<A2AAnf:FIT xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:xsd:003.001">
    <Hdr>
        <Inf>
            <Mtd>TEST</Mtd>
        </Inf>
    </Hdr>
</A2AAnf:FIT>
```

I want to access the `<Mtd>` tag.
XMLQuire shows the path to be `/A2AAnf:MPPPPPP/A2AAnf:FIT/dft:Hdr/dft:Inf/dft:Mtd`, but when I'm trying to parse it using the following code:

```
XmlDocument xmldocument = new XmlDocument();
var xmlNameSpaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmldocument.NameTable);
xmlNameSpaceManager.AddNamespace("A2AAnf", "urn:A2AAnf:xsd:$MPPPPPP");
   try
   {
     xmldocument.LoadXml(m_XML);
     var node = xmldocument.SelectSingleNode("/A2AAnf:MPPPPPP/A2AAnf:FIT/dft:Hdr/dft:Inf/dft:Mtd", xmlNameSpaceManager);
   }
```

I receive the following error:

> namespace prefix 'dft' is not defined

And since I can't find "dft" in my XML, I also tried to remove the "dft" prefix and search for the same string without "dft". This time, nothing was returned.

What am I missing?

Comment: `<Hdr>` is using namespace `urn:iso:std:iso:20022:xsd:003.001` (`<A2AAnf:FIT xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:xsd:003.001">`). I suggest you add the namespace `urn:iso:std:iso:20022:xsd:003.001` with prefix "dft": `xmlNameSpaceManager.AddNamespace("dft", "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:xsd:003.001");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `dft` to your `XmlNamespaceManager`:

```
var xmlNameSpaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmldocument.NameTable);
xmlNameSpaceManager.AddNamespace("A2AAnf", "urn:A2AAnf:xsd:$MPPPPPP");
xmlNameSpaceManager.AddNamespace("dft", "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:xsd:003.001");
```

The prefixes you use in your XPath query have nothing to do with the prefixes used in the XML document. They are instead the prefixes you define in your `XmlNamespaceManager`.